# How can I make VIM a full fledged IDE

Tags: vim, ide

How could I make VIM a full fledged IDE by using different supported plugins for YUI, JQuery and git integration etc.

Comment: Full IDE's know your code intimately from the compiler.  Perhaps you want slightly less than that?

Comment: I agree with Thorbjorn. Vim is a great text editor, but you can't expect feature parity with an IDE dedicated to a specific language. That being said you can probably use `fugitive` for git integration and ctags with a setup including your libraries to get something decent.

Answer (score 4):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE

This has links for various plugins for vim.  Explore on this site and you can find a few more resources and tips for using Vim as your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/

Thoses videos can teach you a lot about vim. I guess you'll be able to do whatever you need to after looking at them.

Comment: Except for those red lines that tell you when you have a syntax error, which is pretty much why 90% of people use IDEs.

Comment: Thats certainly not why I use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my response from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19476/how-can-i-make-vim-a-full-fledged-ide/19490#19490) here as well since that thread was closed.

While there are many plugins for Vim, it really isn't an IDE. However, you *can* get many of the features of IDEs in Vim.

As has been mentioned, you can install plugins manually by searching for them based on features you'd like. If you are looking for something that is already mostly configured, then I'd suggest using [scrooloose's vimfiles](https://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles) project hosted on GitHub. You can clone it into your ~/.vim:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/vimfiles.git ~/.vim
```

You may want to backup your current `~/.vim` directory first.

Once it is downloaded you can install the submodules:

```
cd ~/.vim
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

Finally to use the new plugins you'll have to source the vimrc file in your `~/.vimrc` by adding `source ~/.vim/vimrc` to your `~/.vimrc`.